# Always return Account/Login page if not logged

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I have a problem when return login page if user is not logged.
My ConfigureServices:

```
services.AddAuthentication(CookieScheme) // Sets the default scheme to cookies
            .AddCookie(CookieScheme, options =>
            {
                options.AccessDeniedPath = "/admin/account/accessdenied";
                options.LoginPath = "/admin/account/login";
            });
```

What I want it returns `/admin/account/login` But result always return `/Account/Login`

Comment: How did you set up your routes?

Comment: @Milad I use `app.UseMvcWithDefaultRoute()` in my `Configure`

Comment: Maybe they have return url set in the view check in your view

Comment: Have you used Identity besides cookie authentication?Could you show your complete `ConfigureServices`?

Comment: @XingZou: Pls see it here: http://codepad.org/z5jFrGrq

Comment: Could you try to put above code after the `services.AddIdentity()` in your code, refer to https://github.com/aspnet/Identity/issues/1414

Comment: @HoàngGiaThiên  seems you're trying to use areas but they're not registered in your routes. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/areas?view=aspnetcore-3.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why your code doesn't work but you could try adding the below to your options.

EDIT: If you're using services.ConfigureApplicationCookie in your startup you could try adding the path and redirection to that instead.

```
options.Events = new CookieAuthenticationEvents
{
   OnRedirectToLogin = ctx =>
   {
      ctx.Response.Redirect("/admin/account/login");
      return Task.CompletedTask;
   }
};
```

Comment: Are you using services.ConfigureApplicationCookie in your startup? If you are you could try adding the path and redirection to that instead.

Comment: using `services.ConfigureApplicationCookie`, it works.
Thanks